# How to define which widget shall be placed on homescreen and at which position after factory reset?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-firmware

Assuming I have my apk signed with the platform key and as part of the system:

My app has a widget, which I would like to place on the (system's default - Galaxy Tab P7500, Android 3.2) home screen right after starting the device fresh from factory reset - the same way as the Google Search widget is already there after you're doing a factory reset.

**My question is: where exactly is it defined, which widget should be placed onto the home screen and at which position at factory reset time?**

Comment: This is not possible from the SDK. Custom firmware might be able to do this.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, I know it's not possible via SDK. But I'd like to know where in the lower level system I would need to tweak that; is there a config file, or the homescreen app sources?

Comment: The home screen app sources would typically be from the device manufacturer, since they typically use their own home screen implementation.

Comment: If you are building a custom rom then you should definitely check out the homescreen app. sorry i can't help you with a more precise answer.

Comment: I've edited my question: I mean the vanilla home screen as it comes on Samsung Galaxy Tab P7500 Android 3.2. Wondering, where I'd hook my widget in, via configuration file somewhere in the system or needing to go into the homescreen code (if that's available), assuming I have access to the entire system - where shall I be looking at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `AppWidgetService` and `/data/system/appwidgets.xml`. It matches widget providers (apps) with widget hosts (launchers, etc.). Where exactly the widget appears is controlled by the launcher itself using the appWidgetId for reference. For the default launcher (on ICS), this is kept in the launcher.db database.

So if you add it to `appwidgets.xml` and give it an ID, then insert the proper row in the database, it *should* show up on the homescreen.

Comment: kitkat doesn't have appwidgets.xml --- I'm working on a AOSP, and didn't check /data/system/... of course; I searched whole AOSP source for appwidgets.xml. Am I in right direction?